# How to git push to mapped drive in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, cygwin

I have a Jenkins build box building .NET code (Windows OS, obviously), then copying the new binaries into a local git repo, creating a new branch with the current build number.  The remote master is on a mapped drive (in this case `G:`) and while I can push the new branch to it in Cygwin console, or Git Bash, with Jenkins, the same command returns an error:

```
fatal: 'C:/Program Files/Git/cygdrive/g/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: 'C:/Program Files/Git/cygdrive/g/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The git command in Jenkins shell is this:

```
!/bin/bash
cd ../GIT_REPO
git add -A
git commit -m "Updated CI build for version $BUILD_VERSION_NUMBER_NEW based on $ACCUREVCOMMENT.  This build was triggered by $BUILD_CAUSE"
git branch "RC_$BUILD_VERSION_NUMBER_NEW"
git push file:///cygdrive/g/repo.git "RC_6.0"
git push file:///cygdrive/g/repo.git "RC_$BUILD_VERSION_NUMBER_NEW"
```

Why is Jenkins putting C:/Program Files/Git/cygdrive" in there?  I have Jenkins set up with c:\cygwin\bin for git.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is Jenkins putting C:/Program Files/Git/cygdrive

Because / in Cygwin is translated by the MsysGit (the old git for Windows) by the path where Git is installed.

Nowadays (2018, 5 years later), there would be no need for cygwin anymore, and you could use `file:///G:/path/to/repo my_project` paths.